# Observing result from SDK method by using LiveData

Tags: android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I'm trying to observe the result coming from an SDK (ble device) method by using `LiveData`, but so far no luck.
What I did is the following:

1. wrap the device in a singleton and expose a variable called "status":

   ```
    public MyWrappedDevice {
        private DeviceSDKClass myDevice;
        private static MyWrappedDevice myWrappedDeviceInstance;

        public boolean status;

        public static MyWrappedDevice getInstance(@NonNull final Context context) {
            if (isNull(myWrappedDeviceInstance)) {
                myWrappedDeviceInstance = new MyWrappedDevice(context);
            }

            return myWrappedDeviceInstance;
        }

        private MyWrappedDevice(Context context) {

            ...

            // Note: myDevice is the device's instance and isConnected() the method provided by SDK
            this.status = !isNull(myDevice) && myDevice.isConnected();
        }

        ...
    }
   ```
2. create a ViewModel

   ```
    public class myDeviceViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        private MutableLiveData<Boolean> connected;
        private MyWrappedDevice device;

        public MyDeviceViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);

            this.device = MyWrappedDevice.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
        }

        public LiveData<Boolean> getStatus() {
            if (isNull(connected) {
                connected = new MutableLiveData<>();

                connected.setValue(device.status);
            }

            return connected;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Observe in a fragment

   ```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {          

        ...

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...

            MyDeviceViewModel myModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyDeviceViewModel.class);

            final Observer<Boolean> myObserver = status -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "Is device connected: " + status);
            }

            myModel.getStatus().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), myObserver);
        }
    }
   ```

The above return me a result only at start, no any response when the device get connected/disconnected.
Anybody so kind to address me where I made it wrong or if this is not the right solution for observing method result?
Thanks

p.s. - if possible no `Kotlin` suggestions, I'm not really skilled with that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for such a silly question, of course being an SDK method (and I even wrote it, silly me) no calling means no answer :(